# SQL exception Java Program throwing SQL exception SQL State: 42X01 Error Code: 20000?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, syntax-error, derby

I am writing a Java program to create, write to, edit, delete an instance for a derby database for a college assignment. I have corrected all other errors but am throwing the SQL exception `SQL State:  42X01`

```
Error Code: 20000
          Message: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 99.
          java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at 
          line 1, column 99.
```

I am new to SQL and cannot see where the error is. This is my SQL file:

```
package animaljdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DataBase {    
private static final DataBase DATABASE_INSTANCE = new DataBase();           // Singleton
private DataBase() {}                                                       // a private constructor so no callers can instantiate the singleton object directly
public static synchronized DataBase getInstance() {                         // a public static method for callers to get a reference to the singleton instance
    return DATABASE_INSTANCE;
}
Utility utils = Utility.getInstance();                                      // Create a new Utilities
private final String dbName = "AnimalsDB";                                  
private final String tableName = "Animals";                             // Name of the table
private final String framework = "embedded";
private final String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private final String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
private final String Table = "create table Animals(type varchar(32), color varchar(32), gender varchar(32)," // Query to create Table
                     + " isVertebrate Boolean(32), canSwim Boolean(32))";
Connection conn = null;
private final ArrayList statements = new ArrayList();                   // List of Statements, PreparedStatements, flushed after every method run
PreparedStatement psInsert = null;
PreparedStatement psUpdate = null;
Statement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Properties props = new Properties();                                        // connection properties


public void loadDBdriver() {                                                // Loads the appropriate JDBC driver for this environment/framework. For        
    try {                                                                   // example, if we are in an embedded environment, we load Derby's
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();                                // embedded Driver, <code>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</code>. 
        System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("\nUnable to load the JDBC driver " + driver);
        System.err.println("Please check your CLASSPATH.");
        cnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (InstantiationException ie) {
        System.err.println(
                    "\nUnable to instantiate the JDBC driver " + driver);
        ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        System.err.println(
                    "\nNot allowed to access the JDBC driver " + driver);
        iae.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

protected void createDB() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    System.out.println("Database in " + framework + " mode");
    loadDBdriver();                                                         // Load the desired JDBC driver        
    try {                                                                   // load JDBC
        props.put("user", "user1");                                         // providing a user name and password is optional in the embedded   
        props.put("password", "user1");   
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName + ";create=true", props);  // Setup the connection to the database
        System.out.println("Database" + dbName + "created and connected ");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);                                          // We want to control transactions manually. Autocommit is on by default in JDBC.            
        s = conn.createStatement();                                         // Creating a statement object that we can use for running various SQL statements commands against the database.
        statements.add(s);
        s.execute(Table);                                                   // We create a table...
        System.out.println("Created table " + tableName);
        statements.clear();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }
}

//@param e the SQLException from which to print details.
public static void printSQLException(SQLException e) {                      // Prints details of an SQLException chain to <code>System.err</code>.
    while (e != null)                                                       // Details included are SQL State, Error code, Exception message.
    {                                                                       // Unwraps the entire exception chain to unveil the real cause of the Exception.
        System.err.println("\n----- SQLException -----");
        System.err.println("  SQL State:  " + e.getSQLState());
        System.err.println("  Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode());
        System.err.println("  Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        e = e.getNextException();
    }
}     

 /**
 * @param type
 * @param color
 * @param gender
 * @param isVertebrate
 * @param canSwim
 * @return
 */
public boolean insertObject(String type, String color, String gender, String isVertebrate, String canSwim) {             // This inserts a new animal into the database
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statement
    psInsert = null;

    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psInsert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (type, color, gender, isVertebrate, canSwim) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        statements.add(psInsert);                                       // Prepare for insert()
        psInsert.setString(1, type);                                    // Insert the input
        psInsert.setString(2, color);
        psInsert.setString(3, gender);
            psInsert.setString(4, isVertebrate);
            psInsert.setString(5, canSwim);
        psInsert.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements
        condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }           
    return condition;
}    

ArrayList<Utility> getAnimals() {
    ArrayList<Utility> animalium = new ArrayList<>();                       // To hold the animals we want to return
    rs = null;
    try {                                                                   
        rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY type"); 
        while (rs.next()) {                                                 // temp animal to push to the arraylist                
            Utility temporaryAnimalium = new Utility(rs.getInt(1),          // ID
                                                     rs.getString(2),   // Type
                                                     rs.getString(3),   // Color
                                                     rs.getString(4),   // Gender
                                                     rs.getString(5),       // is Vertebrate
                                                     rs.getString(6));      // canSwim 
            animalium.add(temporaryAnimalium);                              // Add to the arraylist
        }
        try {                                                               // Release resources
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
        statements.clear();                                                 // Clear statements
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    } 
    return animalium;                                                       // Return our animal list
}

 /**
 * @return
 */
public boolean closeDB() {                                                  // Closes out the connection to the database and clears statements
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statements
    statements.clear();                                                     // Clear statements
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        s.execute("DROP TABLE " + tableName);                               // Drop the table
        conn.commit();                                                      // We commit the transaction. Any changes will be persisted to the database now.  

        if (framework.equals("embedded")) {
            try {
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");   // the shutdown=true attribute shuts down Derby
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                if (((se.getErrorCode() == 50000) && ("XJ015".equals(se.getSQLState())))) {
                    System.out.println("Database shut down normally");      // we got the expected exception
                } else {                      
                    System.err.println("Database did not shut down normally");  // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have an unexpected exception (shutdown failed)
                    printSQLException(se);
                }
            }
        }condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    } finally {
        int i = 0;                                                          // release all open resources to avoid unnecessary memory usage
        while (!statements.isEmpty()) {                                     // Statements and PreparedStatements
            Statement st = (Statement)statements.remove(i);                 // PreparedStatement extend Statement
            try {
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                    st = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                printSQLException(sqle);
            }
        }
        try {                                                               //Connection
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
    }       
    return condition;
}

public boolean updateDB(int id, String type, String color, String gender, String isVertebrate, String canSwim) {
    boolean condition = false;                                      // Return statement
    psUpdate = null;
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psUpdate = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET type=?, color=?, gender=?, isVertebrate=?, canSwim=? WHERE id=?");
        statements.add(psUpdate);                                   // Prepare the statement for insertion of values
        psUpdate.setString(1, type);                                    // Update and set integers and strings, inserting the values
        psUpdate.setString(2, color);
        psUpdate.setString(3, gender);
        psUpdate.setString(4, isVertebrate);
            psUpdate.setString(5, canSwim);
            psUpdate.setInt(6, id);
        psUpdate.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute 
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements   
        condition = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle); }          
    return condition;
}

/**
 * @param message
 */
public void reportFailure(String message) {                                 // Reports a data verification failure to System.err with the given message.
    System.err.println("\nData could not be verified: ");
    System.err.println('\t' + message);
}

public boolean delete(int id) {
    boolean state = false;                                                  // Return statement
    psUpdate = null;
    try {                                                                   // Exception handlers
        psUpdate = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE id=?");  // Statement preparation
        statements.add(psUpdate);
        psUpdate.setInt(1, id);                                         // ID we wish to delete
        psUpdate.executeUpdate();                                       // Well....execute 
        statements.clear();                                             // Clear statements   
        state = true;
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        printSQLException(sqle);
    }

    return state;
}

// method to close the dB connection
protected void finishDB(){                                                  // method to close the dB connection
    if (framework.equals("embedded"))
    {
        try
        {
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");       // the shutdown=true attribute shuts down Derby
        }                                                                   // To shut down a specific database only, but keep the
        catch (SQLException se)                                             // engine running (for example for connecting to other
        {                                                                   // databases), specify a database in the connection URL:
            if (( (se.getErrorCode() == 50000)                              //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";shutdown=true");
                    && ("XJ015".equals(se.getSQLState()) ))) {
                System.out.println("Derby shut down normally");             // we got the expected exception
                System.out.println();                                       // Note that for single database shutdown, the expected
            } else {                                                        // SQL state is "08006", and the error code is 45000.
                System.err.println("Derby did not shut down normally");     // if the error code or SQLState is different, we have
                System.out.println();                                       // an unexpected exception (shutdown failed)
                printSQLException(se);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the printed stack trace:

```
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at animaljdbc.DataBase.createDB(DataBase.java:74)
at animaljdbc.AnimalJDBC.main(AnimalJDBC.java:29)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 99.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 99.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

How do I read the stack trace? Where is my error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Use Derby's `ij` tool to interactively debug your DDL statements by entering them into the command line and getting the results back immediately.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL in question appears to be:

```
create table Animals(type varchar(32), color varchar(32),
gender varchar(32), isVertebrate Boolean(32), canSwim Boolean(32)
```

I think column 99 works out to be around the `(32)` after `Boolean`. This suggests to me you should remove `(32)` from after both instances of `Boolean`. (This assumes `Boolean` is a supported type in your DB.)

Your revised SQL is:

```
create table Animals(id int(10), type varchar(32), color varchar(32),
gender varchar(32), isVertebrate String, canSwim String)
```

I suspect that this time around your error (at column 30) relates to the `(10)` immediately following `int` type for the new `id` column. If you remove the `(10)` you should be okay.